# How do I bypass the 16 character limit on username prefixes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Does anyone know how to allow the prefix on a server to be more than 16 numbers/letters long? I would like to make the prefix for my server admins longer than 16 letters.

Example here is the prefix I want to create.

```
[<[Owner]< joecraft15666 >I want colored prefixes[#%]>]
```

Comment: Is this using plugins or mods? And do you mean a user chat prefix? I originally thought you were asking about creating/using a subdomain for your server.

Comment: I was not aware this was possible with vanilla as it only has players and ops

Comment: It is possible it is on my server I just have no plugins no mods so no more than 16 letters

Comment: Ip joepc.moon.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think Bukkit uses this restriction. You should look up how to open and find the Bukkit config.

Everything is explained at their Wiki.

In their config there is a setting how long your prefix or **nickname** can be.

Comment: You answer is ok but could you please add a link to the specific webpage?